# Cardinality of equivalence relations on N

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I asked a similar question yesterday about well ordered sets, now I am having troubles with equivalence relations.

Could someone suggest an injection from a well known set of cardinality
$2^{\aleph_{0}}$ to the set of all equivalence relations of $\mathbb{N}$?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Equivalence classes under *what relation*? Questions should be self-contained. Especially when they are this short.

Comment: Ooops I am sorry, I meant equivalence relations! Pardon me, will fix it right now

Comment: Argh thanks for the link- somehow did not see it myself!

Answer (score 0):

For each subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$, declare all elements of $S$ to be equivalent, and all elements outside $S$ to only be equivalent to themselves. It's not quite an injection, but if you ignore singleton and empty $S$, then it is.

And because there are uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, removing countably many won't hurt, and so the domain of this map is uncountable.

Comment: It seems that the OP has a specific relation in mind. So it might be better to wait until they clarify on this issue before posting an answer.

Comment: I just interpreted it as "I'd like to show how many ways we can partition $\mathbb{N}$, is it at least $2^{\aleph_0}$?". It feels similar in flavor to his other question.